# Optimizing a simple query with join and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - `object_72194_` and `object_72197_` respectively:

```
| attr_72195_ |     | attr_72198_ | attr_72199_  |
| 2013-07-31  |     |   a         | 2013-07-31   |
| 2013-07-30  |     |   b         | 2013-07-31   |
| 2013-07-29  |     |   c         | 2013-07-30   |
| 2013-07-28  |     |   d         | 2013-07-29   |
```

For each row in the first table I want to get the value of the field `attr_72198_` from the second table where `attr_72199_` less or equal to `attr_72195_`. So, in this case the result will look like this:

```
|attr_72195_  | attr_72196_  |
|2013-07-31   | a            |
|2013-07-30   | c            |
|2013-07-29   | d            |
|2013-07-28   | NULL         |
```

I want to get value per row. Now my working query looks like this:

```
SELECT f1.attr_72195_, t.attr_72198_ AS attr_72196_ 
FROM object_72194_ f1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
 SELECT id, attr_72198_, attr_72199_ FROM object_72197_ t 
) AS t ON t.attr_72199_ <= f1.attr_72195_ 
WHERE ( f1.id_obj = 72194 ) AND (t.attr_72199_ = (
 SELECT MAX(attr_72199_) FROM object_72197_ t 
 WHERE attr_72199_ <= f1.attr_72195_
) OR t.attr_72199_ IS NULL
```

) ORDER BY f1.id_order DESC

It works as expected. But it does not seem to be quite optimal because of the subquery in the last `WHERE` block. One programmer advised me to use one more join with grouping instead, but I just do not know how.
Thank you!

EDIT:
Removed unnecessary ordering inside subqueries and checked both queries (mine and with joins instead of a subquery) and got interesting result. EXPLAIN returned five rows for the version with a subquery and four rows for the version with joins (id column). In "rows" column I got 13 rows for the subquery version and 18 rows in total for join version. So, have to check against large data to decide what version to use.

EDIT:
Oh, this query with joins turned out to be incorrect, because it groups results by the column

EDIT:
The question is still open. The problem appears when there are duplicates in the second table. As a result, both queries return as many rows as in the second table. But I need just a value per row. Just as I showed from the very first in the example with values "a", "b", "c" and "d".

EDIT:
Finally, I did it. I added grouping by unique field in the first table and returned the previous grouping. So the query now looks like this:

```
SELECT f1.attr_72195_, f2.attr_72198_ AS attr_72196_ 
FROM object_72194_ f1
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT f1.attr_72195_, MAX(f2.attr_72199_) AS attr_72199_
 FROM object_72194_ f1 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN object_72197_ f2 ON f1.attr_72195_ >= f2.attr_72199_
 GROUP BY f1.attr_72195_
) o
ON f1.attr_72195_ = o.attr_72195_
LEFT OUTER JOIN object_72197_ f2 ON f2.attr_72199_ = o.attr_72199_
GROUP BY f1.id, attr_72195_ ORDER BY f1.id_order DESC
```

Simple and elegant.

Comment: Before dealing with the performance, find the person who named your tables and columns and kill him.

Comment: It would be easier to follow your example with cleaner table and column names.

Comment: Still, for purposes of illustrating your problem? Fixing up the table and column names would make the example easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding the correlated sub queries (not tested):-

```
SELECT f1.attr_72195_, MIN(f2.attr_72198_)
FROM object_72194_ f1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT f1.attr_72195_, MAX(f2.attr_72199_) As Max_attr_72199_
    FROM object_72194_ f1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN object_72197_ f2
    ON f1.attr_72195_ >= f2.attr_72199_
    GROUP BY f1.attr_72195_
) Sub1
ON f1.attr_72195_ = Sub1.attr_72195_
LEFT OUTER JOIN object_72197_ f2
ON f2.attr_72199_ = Sub1.Max_attr_72199_
GROUP BY f1.attr_72195_
```

Do a LEFT JOIN between the 2 tables, and get the max date from the 2nd table which is less than or equal to the first table. Inner join the results of that back to the 1st table and left join to the 2nd table. Not sure which value of attr_72198_  you want when the dates are duplicates so I have just used the min function to get the smallest one.

EDIT

Try this which should cope with duplicates on the first table.

```
SELECT f1.attr_72195_, f2.attr_72198_
FROM object_72194_ f1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT f1.attr_72195_, MAX(f2.attr_72199_) As Max_attr_72199_
    FROM object_72194_ f1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN object_72197_ f2
    ON f1.attr_72195_ >= f2.attr_72199_
    GROUP BY f1.attr_72195_
) Sub1
ON f1.attr_72195_ = Sub1.attr_72195_
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT attr_72199_, MIN(attr_72198_) AS attr_72198_
    FROM object_72197_ 
    GROUP BY attr_72199_
) f2
ON f2.attr_72199_ = Sub1.Max_attr_72199_
```

Comment: Column name was wrong in the group by I think (was just the table name). Try now. If not will have to set up an SQL fiddle.

Comment: The error is because of the cross join. I've just tried to run the subquery inside inner join and got the same error.

Comment: Fixed it now. Created test tables and had a play and seems to work. Cross join wasn't the problem (although it caused another issue), rather the use of MAX when checking a value at the end of the sub query.

Comment: Absolutelly, great! Works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, man! Sorry, but it is incorrect. The result is not right if there are duplicates in the first table. For example, if there are two rows with "2013-07-31", your query will return a row with "2013-07-31" only once bacause of the last grouping. But as I said from teh very first, I need a value per raw.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I worked to your example data, hence the comment in my answer about using MIN. It actually makes it easier if you want them all for that day. Just knock off the MIN() around that column and knock off the group by.

Comment: Thank you, sir! But still there is another problem - duplicates in the second table. My query based on a subquery and your query return as many rows as in the second table. But I need a value per table. Say, the first one value.

Comment: Ah, right. Misunderstood you. Try the new suggestion (basically getting the min value for each day from the 2nd table in a sub query)